# Create a JSON TYPE column in BigQuery by grouping column values

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table in BQ with the following schema:

```
user_id,format,sum_value,total_occ
00444e,big,0.38463,38
00444e,mid,0.38032,1042
00555e,sml,0.64651,128
00666e,mid,0.55073,244
```

And I want to group the data by the `user_id` and have all the other data in a JSON_TYPE column like this:

```
user_id,json_data
00444e,{"big":{"sum_value":0.38463,"total_occ":38},"mid":{"sum_value":0.38032,"total_occ":1042}}
00555e,{"sml":{"sum_value":0.64651,"total_occ":128}}
00666e,{"big":{"sum_value":0.55073,"total_occ":244}}
```

i've been thinkerig with `ARRAY_AGG`,`JSON_OBJECT` functions but with no result. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer:

```
with
data as
(
  select "00444e" as user_id, "big" as format, 0.38463 as sum_value, 38 as total_occ union all
  select "00444e" as user_id, "mid" as format, 0.38032 as sum_value, 1042 as total_occ union all
  select "00555e" as user_id, "sml" as format, 0.64651 as sum_value, 128 as total_occ union all
  select "00666e" as user_id, "mid" as format, 0.55073 as sum_value, 244 as total_occ
)
select 
  user_id, 
  json_object(
    array_agg(format order by format),
    array_agg(struct(sum_value, total_occ) order by format)
  ) as json_data
from data
group by 1
```

Longer answer:

```
with
data as
(
  select "00444e" as user_id, "big" as format, 0.38463 as sum_value, 38 as total_occ union all
  select "00444e" as user_id, "mid" as format, 0.38032 as sum_value, 1042 as total_occ union all
  select "00555e" as user_id, "sml" as format, 0.64651 as sum_value, 128 as total_occ union all
  select "00666e" as user_id, "mid" as format, 0.55073 as sum_value, 244 as total_occ
),
t1 as
(
  select 
    user_id, 
    format,
    struct(sum_value, total_occ) as vals,
  from data
),
t2 as 
(
  select 
    user_id,
    array_agg(format order by format) as format_arr,
    array_agg(vals order by format) as vals_arr
  from t1
  group by 1
)
select 
  user_id, 
  json_object(format_arr, vals_arr)
from t2
;
```

In bigquery, equivalent of a json object is a struct.
So we need to create a struct for the inner part of your expected output.
That's why we create a struct in t1 to create an object of sum_Value and total_occ.

Then we need to create an object from an unknown number of rows by grouping by. So we need an aggregation function which brings several rows together and outputs a json object.
Json_object function does it in the second signature.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_object

To be able to do it, we need to create arrays of keys (format) and values (struct of sum_value and total_occ). We also need them to be in the same order.
So in t2, we group by userid, and create arrays by using "order by format" to be sure about the ordering.

In the final output, we use the json_object function to bring keys and values together as an object.

Comment: Awesome! thanks a bunch for the answer and the explanation